# How do I take output after giving the input in python?

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python I just learned about the input command (i am using IDLE)
the input command but when I enter the input the output is not displayed I entered the print command.

now matter how many times i try to input the output is not displayed.
[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0M57.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem understanding IDLE, make sure you type the Enter button after every line and you should see the >>> sign:

```
>>> str_age = input("What is your present age ?\n")
What is your present age ?
15
>>> present = int(str_age)
>>> future = present + 5
>>> future
20
```

Something else about IDLE, it returns the value of every variable or type you enter:

```
>>> 5
5
>>> True
True
>>> 'test'
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the code editor instead of the IDLE to write your code, but in order to call a method and have it print an output, you could do something like this:

```
>>> def fAge(currAge):
    str_age = input('Whats your age?')
    present = int(str_age)
    return 'your age in the future is %s' %(present+5)

>>> fAge()
Whats your age?12
'your age in the future is 17'
```